# Are there any extreme instances where a change of basis can change the eigenvalues of the transformed matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

I would like to know if there are any rare cases where performing a basis change for describing a transformation on a different basis also changes its eigenvalues.
I know that in general this does not happen, but I would like to know if there are any extreme cases where it does happen.

Comment: An eigenvalue of a linear transformation $T:V\to W$ is defined as $\lambda$ such that there is nonzero $v\in V$ which satisfies $Tv=\lambda v$; This description is basis-free, so changing basis cannot change eigenvalues

Comment: @user160738:  Presumably you meant $T:V\to V$?  Unless the range is a subspace of the domain, there cannot be an eigenvector.

Comment: @hardmath Oh, yes; thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. If $T: V \rightarrow V$ is a linear operator where $A$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to a basis $\mathcal{B}$, and $C$ is the matrix of $T$ with respect to another basis $\mathcal{B}^{'}$, then we necessarily have that $A=PCP^{-1}$ for some invertible matrix P. In other words, $A$ is conjugate (or similar) to $C$. Matrices that are similar always have the exact same eigenvalues.

Comment: Do you know if something like this could happen in the field of functional analysis(i.e. in infinite dimensional spaces)?